# Format string to date Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm fetching from an API a date string that is formatted like this : DD_MM_YYYY_hh_mm__ss

I want to display the string in this format : DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the underscore sequences with the appropriate characters based on their position within the input string:

```js
function convertDate(date) {
    return date.replace(/_+/g, (_, n) => (n < 10) ? "/" : (n > 10) ? ":" : " ");
}

console.log(convertDate("DD_MM_YYYY_hh_mm__ss"));
```

Or slightly simpler:

```js
function convertDate(date) {
    let n = 0; return date.replace(/_+/g, () => "// ::"[n++]);
}

console.log(convertDate("DD_MM_YYYY_hh_mm__ss"));
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```js
const str = '18_03_2022_12_21_34'
// to string
const res = str.split('_')
const r = res.slice(0, 3).join('/') + ' ' + res.slice(-3).join(':')
console.log(r)
// or to date
console.log(new Date(res.slice(0, 3).join('/').split('/').reverse().join('/') + ' ' + res.slice(-3).join(':')))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Vue Filter**

Code:

```js
Vue.filter('stringTodateTime', function ( dateTimeString ) {
    if (!dateTimeString) return ''
    return dateTimeString.replace(/_+/g, (_, n) => (n < 10) ? "/" : (n > 10) ? ":" : " ");
})
```

Usage:

```js
{{ 12_04_2021_12_59_34 | stringTodateTime }}
```